# How to do type as you search in elasticsearch when searching multiple value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Given that I want to do a search query like

`query: I am here`

I want elasticsearch return the documents contains exactly consecutive values - `I am here`  what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Dow-voting because you need to at least post an attempt. Please read the rules

Comment: Try the `match_phrase` query ;-)

Comment: @Yeikel what do you mean by attempt? I have tried multiple queries but it is still failing

Comment: @Val I tried `match_phrase` However if I am typing things like `I ha`, ES is not returning all the documents contains `I ha..`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the phrase suggester

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html